# What is the fastest known algorithm for computing a 1.99-approximation of Vertex Cover?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, exp-time-algorithms

It is [known](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37713/is-the-current-best-approximation-ratio-for-vertex-cover-problem-also-a-lower-bo) that computing $(\sqrt 2 -\epsilon)$-approximation for VC is NP-hard and that UGC implies that even a $(2 -\epsilon)$-approximation is hard.

There is also a [parameterized algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000017302222?via%3Dihub) for computing a $\alpha$-approximation of VC (for $\alpha\in[1,2]$).

Considering the standard (non-parameterized) problem and non-polynomial algorithms:

- **What is the fastest known algorithm for computing a $1.99$-approximation?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think for getting 1.99-approximation algorithm this [paper](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/9424/) by Manurangsi and Trevisan, has the current fastest algorithm.